# iText 7 Java HtmlConverter.convertToPdf

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext7

When using the `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf` to convert `html` to pdf which has the `input type checkbox` I get:

```
  [main] ERROR InputTagWorker - Input type checkbox is not supported
```

Comment: Hi Allen, you are already in contact with one of our sales reps. You will get a reply through that channel.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the core focus of iText (as a company) is still in .pdf documents.

Similar to iText5 (http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-convert-html-pdf), not all html tags are (at this point in time) supported.

But, with the latest pdfHtml addon, you can at least write your own custom TagWorker class, that will get invoked whenever a specific tag is encountered. That should make it easy to implement your own handler for checkboxes. And maybe in future, iText will provide you with theirs.

Kind regards,
Joris